# Replace first and last occurrence of a string with another

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, apache-velocity

Given a string "[ something that may contain a brace ], like so]". The start and end brackets need to be replaced with ( and ) or alternatively removed. I am really looking for the replacement and not the removal. Braces on the inside of the string need to remain

The default given by AppSync is as follows:

```
#set( $valStr = $vals.toString().replace("[","(").replace("]",")") )
```

Can anyone help to to do this with one line.

The code above would make the mentioned string "( something that may contain a brace ), like so)"

What I need is:

"( something that may contain a brace ], like so)"

Answer (score 1):

I think there´s only a workaround for this problem. You can use replaceFirst after you replaced all square brackets: `#set($vals = "[ something that may contain a brace ], like so]") #set( $valStr = $vals.toString().replace("[","(").replace("]",")") ) $valStr.replaceFirst(")","]"))`

Comment: I think this is the step in the correct direction. However, this does not solve the problem.